# C# Asp net core How to call database context outside of controllers

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a question related to the use of database contexts outside the controller, namely, how to call the database context in a regular class?
To communicate with the database, I use: EF Core

I used options like this:

```
private readonly MSSQLContext _context;

    public BookingController(MSSQLContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Alternative

```
            using (MSSQLContext context=new MSSQLContext())
        {
            context.get_Users.ToList();
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
      services.AddDbContext<MSSQLContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

MSSQLContext.cs

```
        public MSSQLContext()
    {
    }

    public MSSQLContext(DbContextOptions<MSSQLContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<VIVT_Core_Aud.Models.Core.Logger_Model> Logger_Models { get; set; }
```

and more tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject context using DI(dependency injection). I am showing you an example of repository pattern. You can search for "Repository pattern EF Core C# examples" will give you lots of examples or blogs to follow. [Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Check out below example..

> MyRepository.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Data.Services
{
    public class MyRepository: IMyRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private MyAppContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<MyRepository> _logger;

        public MyRepository(MyAppContext context, ILogger<MyRepository> logger)
        {
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyTable> GetMyTableData()
        {
          return _context.MyTable.ToList();
         }
}
}
```

> IMyRepository.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Data.Services
{
    public interface IMyRepository
        {
           //Interface implementation
            IEnumerable<MyTable> GetMyTableData();
         }
}
```

> Startup.cs of MVC project

```
services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbConnString")));            

//Scope of repository should be based on your project used, I recommend to check lifetime & scope based your project needs.     
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

> Mycontroller.cs

```
using MyApp.Data.Services;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IMyRepository myRepository)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _myRepository = myRepository ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myRepository));                
            
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
public IActionResult GetAllData()
        {
            var result =  _myRepository.GetMyTableData();
            return Json(result);

        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject the context into whatever class you need to call into and register that class with the DI framework in your startup class.

For instance,

```
services.AddTransient<YourType>();

class YourType
{
    public YourType(YourDbContext context) { ... }
}
```

Comment: "Error CS7036 Missing argument corresponding to the required formal parameter "context" from "Bitrix24_API.Bitrix24_API (MSSQLContext)" "
And how to overcome this?
Maybe I'm asking stupid questions :(

Comment: @Shadow_VRN36 How are you instantiating your class? Via DI or with the new keyword?

Comment: You need to use proper constructor for your dBcontext into repository.

Comment: I have added a sample for repository pattern into MVC project using EF Core. I hope this helps you.